# Proof arguments in Coq

Tags: logic, coq, theorem-proving

I'm trying to define a function on a weakly-specified type in Coq. Specifically, I have a type that is defined inductively by a set of recursive constructors, and I want to define a function that is only defined when the argument has been constructed using a subset of these.

To be more concrete, I have the following type definition:

```
Inductive Example : Set :=
  | Example_cons0 : nat -> Example
  | Example_cons1 : Example -> Example
  .
```

Now, I have a function that only applies to the ground case. (The following definition will not work obviously, but is meant to suggest my intent.)

```
Definition example (x:Example) : nat :=
  match x with
    | Example_cons0 n => n
  end.
```

Ideally, I'd like to communicate that my argument, x, has been constructed using a subset of the general type constructors, in this case, Example_cons0. I thought that I could do this by defining a predicate that states this fact and passing a proof of the predicate as an argument. For example:

```
Definition example_pred (x:Example) : Prop :=
  match x with
    | Example_cons0 _ => True
    | _ => False
  end.
```

And then (following the recommendation given by Robin Green) something like,

```
Definition example2 (x:Example) : example_pred x -> nat :=
  (use proof to define example2?)
```

Unfortunately, I'm not sure how I would go about doing any of this. I'm not even sure that this is the correct way to define restricted functions on weakly-specified types.

Any guidance, hints, or suggestions would be strongly appreciated!
- Lee

Update:

Following recommendations by jozefg, the example function can be defined as:

```
Definition example (x:Example) : example_pred x -> nat :=
  match x with
    | Example_cons0 n => fun _ => n
    | _               => fun proof => match proof with end 
  end.
```

See his comments for details. This function can be evaluated using the following syntax, which also demonstrates how proof terms are represented in Coq:

```
Coq < Eval compute in Example.example (Example.Example_cons0 0) (I : Example.example_pred (Example.Example_cons0 0)).
    = 0
    : nat
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I'd write this as a simplified example

Consider a simple data type

```
Inductive Foo :=
| Bar : nat -> Foo
| Baz.
```

And now we define a helpful function

```
Definition bar f :=
  match f with
    | Bar _ => True
    | Baz   => False
  end.
```

And finally what you want to write:

```
Definition example f :=
  match f return bar f -> nat with
    | Bar n => fun _ => n
    | Baz   => fun p => match p with end
  end.
```

This has the type `forall f : Foo, bar f -> nat`. This works by making sure that in the case that `example` was not supplied a `Bar`, that the user must supply a proof of false (impossible).

This can be called like this

```
example (Bar n) I
```

But the problem is, you may have to manually prove some term is constructed by `Bar`, otherwise how is Coq supposed to know?

Comment: Clever, the code given certainly works, but can you explain some more about the way the definition works. It seems like this problem necessarily involves the Curry-Howard isomorphism because, on the one hand, I'm trying to define a computational function, and on the other hand, the definition involves a proof argument. It seems that your solution and Green's approaches the problem from two different directions. Green uses proof terms to define the computation, while you describe the proof term as a computation.

Comment: Specifically, I feel like the way that you reduce the proof term to False using the second matching construct is subtle and indirect. Is there a more intuitive way to handle this problem.

Comment: @LarryLee Yep, essentially this is making heavy use of dependent types. The type of the second argument depends on the first. If the first argument is a `Bar`, then the second argument is just a trivial witness for true. If it's a Baz, then it's a witness for `False` which we can use to prove anything

Comment: @LarryLee As for whether this can be made clearer, perhaps, it's easier to write than actually writing a proof term since most tactics (`auto` and friends) will just give you back a constant `0` since that "proves" your goal. This can be fixed with more specific types of course. This is a pretty common idiom in Coq so it may just be something to get used to

Comment: Thanks, I suppose that there is just a single question remaining for now. How can the proof term actually be represented so that the function can be applied? Evaluating the given function returns a new function that expects a proof term for example_pred (a.k.a bar). For example, Coqtop returns the following trace:
 Coq < Eval compute in Example.example (Example.Example_cons0 5).
     = fun _ : True => 5
     : Example.example_pred (Example.Example_cons0 5) -> nat

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are on the right lines. You want:

```
Definition example2 (x:Example) (example_pred x) : nat :=
```

and how to proceed further would depend on what you wanted to prove.

You might find it helpful to make a definition by proving with tactics, using the Curry-Howard correspondence:

```
Definition example2 (x:Example) (example_pred x) : nat.
Proof.
  some proof
Defined.
```

Also, I'd like to point out that the `sig` and `sigT` types are often used to combine "weakly-specified types" with predicates to constrain them.

Comment: Thanks for the very prompt response, I'm glad to hear that I'm at least working toward the right direction. Unfortunately, When I try to use the example given in your second code snippet, I get the following syntax error: `> Definition example2 (x:Example) (example_pred x) : nat.
>                                                ^
Syntax error: [Prim.name] or ':' expected (in [constr:closed_binder])`

Comment: Is there another syntax that can be used to pass the proof for "example_pred x" as an argument?

Comment: Ok, I think that I've figured that out. It appears that the correct syntax is: "Definition example2 (x:Example) : example_pred x -> nat". When I enter this in coqtop, I'm correctly dropped into the interactive proof environment.

Comment: I'm now left with the challenge of generating the correct function using proof terms. The function that I'm trying to define simply returns one of the arguments that was passed to the constructor (please see my second code block). I'm faced with a proof environment with one hypothesis, "x : Example.Example", and the following goal, "Example.example_pred x -> nat". how do I generate the function described in my second code block as a proof of this goal?